# JMeter read from csv file to array

Tags: arrays, csv, jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

Is there any possibility to read files from .csv into array of variables?

Instead of getting:

`https://loadtest.com/mo/75245.json`

`https://loadtest.com/mo/190554MHG.json`

`https://loadtest.com/mo/190223MJG.json`

`https://loadtest.com/mo/198533FTR.json`

...

I would like to get an array:

`https://loadtest.com/mo/75245.190554MHG.190223MJG.198533FTR.19023.HGTYTRWEYRWEHF.1922MHGDGO.json`

Does anybody have some idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction):

- [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) - to read your CSV file into a JMeter Variable
- [__split()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__split) - to "split" the aforementioned JMeter Variable holding CSV file content into separate variables using any suitable delimited (comma, tabulation symbol, newline, whatever)

Comment: Thank you for the hint Dmitri! I think I didn't use properly __split()... this is how I did it...do you see a mistake by any chance? String Articles = "${__StringFromFile(C:\docs\loadtest\articles.csv,,,)}";
String[] Articles1 = Articles.split(",");
vars.put("Articles1",Articles1);

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this, if you don't want to use Groovy, can be using text editor that supports regex (like Notepad++) to restructure your CSV, so that multiple lines are collapsed into a single multi value line.

An example for Notepad++ would be replacing all instances of:
`^(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+)\R`
With
`$1 $2 $3`
To collapse every 3 lines of text into a single line.

Then you can just use that one line as a single variable in JMeter. This way I've passed multiple comma separated Ids into an array in an Http request. Remember to use a different delimiter in JMeter CSV Data Set Config for actual CSV columns, than the one used to delimit your multiple values.